# css files are not loaded because strict MIME checking is enabled when using spring security5

Tags: css, spring-security, mime-types, tomcat9

Spring security 5 blocks my css files when content type option is "nosniff". spring security does not block  extern css files from other sites or css files brought by frameworks like struts2, it does however block css files that I create even if the file is empty like this one:

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="reclamation/css/style2.css"/>`
the error message is :
**Refused to apply style from {fileName} because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.**
I validated the css file with no errors but still got the problem.
here are the headers:

> Request URL:
> http://localhost:8080/reclamation/reclamation/js/style2.css Referrer
> Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store,
> max-age=0, must-revalidate Content-Language: en Content-Length: 1123
> Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2020 10:45:08
> GMT Expires: 0 Pragma: no-cache X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> X-Frame-Options: DENY X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Accept:
> text/css,*/*;q=0.1 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language:
> en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,ar;q=0.7 Cache-Control: no-cache Connection:
> keep-alive Cookie: JSESSIONID=EA9A3D0AC31CDB51C68E0806CD5C32E1 DNT: 1
> Host: localhost:8080 Pragma: no-cache Referer:
> http://localhost:8080/reclamation/list-complaint.action
> Sec-Fetch-Dest: style Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors Sec-Fetch-Site:
> same-origin User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5
> Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Mobile Safari/537.36

permitAll is not a solution because it permits access but keeps security filters

`<http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>` works but it deletes X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff for the css files. by the way security="none" solves the problem when working with eclipse but when I deploy the war directly in tomcat9 it is ignored and css files are not loaded.

my configuration: struts2, jdk8 tomcat 9.0.19 , spring security 5.1.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had filter who was changing all files to "text/html"

```
public class CharacterSetFilter implements Filter {
 
public void destroy() {}

public void doFilter(
  ServletRequest request, 
  ServletResponse response, 
  FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");//this line was the problem
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    next.doFilter(request, response);
}

// ...
```

}

Comment: That was the problem, how you made a Workaround? deleting the line and doing nothing else?

Comment: I forgot. I did many things: one of them add
`<mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>`
in web.xml
in applicationContextSecurity.xml I added:
`<intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll"/> `
I hope it  will help